# for statement implementation for try counting in python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I want, using the array count and for statement, to check in a loop if the input value is in range [0, 2] printing "You exceeded the    maximum amount of tries" when the user tries to input a wrong value more than 3 times, the code is:

```
a=int(raw_input("a "))
count=[1,2,3]
attemp=1
for i in count:
   while (a<0 or a>2):
      print ("WRONG") 
      a=int(raw_input("a"))
      if (a>=0 and a<= 2):
         i=4
      else:
         i+=1
   attempt=i
if(attempt<=3):
   print ("You needed %i" %attempt)
else:
   print ("You exceeded the maximum amount of tries")
```

I encounter a logical problem when I execute the code, I can input an infinite amount of non valid values when the maximum amount of tries should be 3,  so it won't reach `print ("You exceeded the maximum amount of tries")`

Comment: You have typos and indentation problems in a few places. In this the actual code?

Comment: Your inner loop essentially defeats the purpose of the outer loop.  Why not have a *single* loop that both keeps count of the attempts and also checks for valid input.  Exit the loop if either the input is valid or the maximum number of attempts has been exceeded.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes it is, I'm learning python from scratch so I didn't notice some typos and indentation errors

Answer (score -1):

You are over-complicating things. How about this :

```
a = -1
attempt = 0
while not 0 <= a <= 2: 
    attempt += 1
    if attempt == 3:
        break
    a = raw_input('a ')

if attempt < 3:
    print ("You needed %s" % attempt)
else:
    print ("You exceeded the maximum amount of tries")
```